# Pinch Zoom only on a image (and not the rest of the page)

Tags: responsive-design, pinchzoom

I resume the situation:

I have a responsive website with a "zoom box" (jquery script that makes a overlay black cache and shows an image over the page).

I want to enable the pinch zoom on this "layer" of my website (or at least on the image).

But when we use "pinch zoom", all the website is affected!

How can i make this pinch zoom being enabled only for that image (or better this overlay)...

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777800/jquery-mobile-pinch-zoom-image-only?rq=1

Comment: Yeah i saw it. But i don't know how implement it in my code (jquery).
But im searching now in this way! Thanx.