# Enable pinch zoom only on several img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, extjs

### Context

It's a web and Cordova application (same codebase) which display a carousel with 0-3 picture and 0-1 video.

This application is developed with ExtJS and I use the Ext.carousel xtype to display my carousel.

I accept vanilla solution.

My viewport :

```
width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no
```

---

### Expected Behavior

I want to enabled pinch zoom on image into my carousel but only on image and with the closest render to the Android gallery.

---

### What I have do

I found a "solution" that consists of update my viewport when I open the fullscreen carousel with:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes
```

And I reset my viewport with default value when user close them.

But this solution isn't clean for me because first, I have to override the native code of Ext.carousel for authorize the left/right "touchslide" to move into my zoomed picture because without this, it was just slide to the next or previous picture.

Then it breaks my carousel because when an image is zoomed, it is possible to move between two images.

[image]

---

### What I have tried

1 - [JQuery Mobile Pinch Zoom Image Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777800/jquery-mobile-pinch-zoom-image-only). But it's only allow to "*zoom*" and not move into zoomed image.

2 - Several zoom or lightbox library like https://www.cssscript.com/image-zoomer-moible-pinchzoom/ or https://manuelstofer.github.io/pinchzoom/ or https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox and more